# how to: r = requests.get(driver_current_url)

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

```
 r = requests.get(driver_current_url)
```

How to request and use the url from the driver in the request.
(also the request request the url thru the driver)

```
Driver = PATH = "C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
```

Comment: What driver?  I can't tell what you are asking here.

Comment: PATH = "C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were partly right, use:

```
url = driver.current_url
r = requests.get(url)
```